# How do I join 2 horizontal cells' content in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-auto-fill

I have a sheet and i want to join the content of each two consecutive cells in one column to a new column like this:

```
=A1&" "&A2
=A3&" "&A4
=A5&" "&A6
...
```

But when I try to Auto-fill it doesn't get the pattern right.
It messes up in many cells and duplicate others.

P.s: I'm trying to make it like this,
(break line before the next layer content)

```
=A1&"
"&A2
```

TLDR;
i want to make this repeating pattern

1,2

3,4

5,6

7,8

9,10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,(ROW()-1)*2+1) & " " & INDEX(A:A,(ROW()-1)*2+2)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

The `ROW()` expressions are an easy way to generate a sequence of values like *1, 3, 5, 7,...* and *2, 4, 6, 8,...*.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks man.

Comment: @RooTenshi  Glad to help!